# Disable SD card access

Tags: windows, wmi

Is there a way i can disable access to SD card programmatically using WMI or by modifying registry programmatically?
So far i was successful in disabling USB by modifying the 
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR" registry. However this does not block the SD card for some reason.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can block selected external devices using lock folder xp and universal shield softwares

Comment: I want to achieve this programmatically. (c#)

Comment: oh, did you tried blocking external devices? you can do that in c# I think